# How to detect if a user writes a specific sentence?

Tags: autohotkey

So, I want to detect if a user writes a specific sentence on the keyboard, and if so afterwards perform a function.

For example, if the user writes:

```
if user types /hello
```

script activates and for example puts out

```
Send, Hello. How are you today?
```

Comment: [Hotstrings](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm)

Comment: This is covered very clearly in the documentation and many of the samples. Did you try looking there?

Comment: I did like 5 googles before asking. I guess my google ninja is down lately. Will check out hotstrings. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation for [Hotstrings](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm), your example would look like this:

`::if user types /hello::Send, Hello. How are you today?`

Although, this requires typing an additional "ending character" such as a space or tab to trigger the transformation.

To *immediately* replace the text after entering the last character you add the `*` [option](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm#Options):

`:*:if user types /hello::Send, Hello. How are you today?`